# BeautifulSoup how to parse a element without tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a little problem with parse. I have body =

```
<div class='contact'>
    <i class='fa fa phone'></i>
    Text what I want
</div>
```

And I have a lot of similar code. I use =

```
    def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text



def get_all_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tds = soup.find('div', class_='col-xs-7 insInfoRow onlyGal')
    link = []
    for i in tds:
            link.append(i)
    return link
```

I want only this text. Help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code for you. `.text` can get text content directly from element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div class='contact'>
    <i class='fa fa phone'></i>
    Text what I want
</div>
<div class='contact'>
    <i class='fa fa phone'></i>
    Text what I want too
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='contact')
print([div.text.strip() for div in divs])
```

PS: `.strip()` can remove spaces.

Comment: Dude sorry but I made a mistake. I use .find_all. Can u help me with it?

Comment: Dude how to add in list what I parsed?

Comment: @RamzeyXD do you mean `["Text what I want", "Text what I want too"]`, is it?

Comment: Yeah. Because I use .append in the loop  but it gives me html

Comment: @RamzeyXD use list comprehension.